# How to fix : build file 'C:\Users\nayye\AndroidStudioProjects\ridewave_b\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24

Tags: flutter, firebase, build.gradle

I am using flutter for the first time, after running main.dart I am getting the following error.
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\nayye\AndroidStudioProjects\ridewave_b\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
> Could not create plugin of type 'AppPlugin'.
> > Could not generate a decorated class for type AppPlugin.
> > com/android/build/api/component/Component

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I ran flutter doctor -v and there isnt any problem with android studio.

Comment: Do you have proper internet connection when run your code? If not please connect internet to your device then try to run the app. Hope will work. If not please share the error log here.

Comment: I do have a stable internet connection, and the error is posted above (this is what i get after running the main.dart file). Can you please elaborate what error log you are asking if it is not the one above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced simliar situation you met,
In Light of my experience, Removing gradle file and rebuilding Projects initially is a best solution about gradle setting problems.

Comment: I manually deleted those files and then rebuild it but the error is still there. I ran the ./gradlew clean command but the error is same as the one mentioned above

Comment: How about delete project and re make project from scratch?

Comment: That seemed to work, thanks!

Comment: If My answer is helpful to you, Please upvote or select my answer. thx :)